# Vuejs prop does not get updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have following scenario. I have this component

```
<div class="flex items-start gap-4">
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-4">
    <div class="border shadow p-2">
      <chart :config="lineConfig" ref="linechart" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <options
    :chart="$refs.linechart"
    :resolution="lineResolution"
    :maxTicksLimit="lineMaxTicksLimit"
  ></options>
</div>
```

In my `options.vue`

```
export default Vue.extend({
  props: ['resolution', 'maxTicksLimit', 'chart'],
  watch: {
    resolution() {
      this.chart.update()
    },
    maxTicksLimit() {
      this.chart.update()
    },
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.chart)
    }, 100)
  },
})
```

I always gets `undefined`. I understand that the component did not mounted yet and i would need to use `$nextTick()`, but if i pass `:chart="$refs"` then i see in the console `{ linechart: ... }`

Also a sidenote: If i interact with the chart, for example using `chart.update()`, then `this.chart` is no more undefined.

My goal is to pass the chart with `$refs.linechart` so i can use the methods of the component

Comment: Pretty sure `$refs.linechart` doesn't exist when you are expecting it to. Try getting the value in a method or watch.

Comment: `$refs` is not reactive, unfortunately. You will have to provide a local variable as a prop, and assign this local variable inside the `mounted` hook of the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

From Vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#ref)

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs
> themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot
> access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! $refs is
> also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in
> templates for data-binding.

So that explains pretty much the entire behaviour. If you are binding `$this.linechart` it will pass undefined at first render because the ref doesn't exist yet. If you are binding `$refs` you pass a reference to `$refs` object which latter is updated in a non-reactive way.

I can think only of one solution. Render the `options` component only after the parent has been rendered, to have `$refs` object populated, and don't count on its reactivity. Like:

```html
  <options
    v-if="rendered"
    :chart="$refs.linechart"
    :resolution="lineResolution"
    :maxTicksLimit="lineMaxTicksLimit"
  ></options>
```

```js
data(){
    rendered: false
},
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => this.rendered = true)
}
```